# ref and Populate in mongoose to a specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I want to be able to create a product and in the package I of that product I wan to be able to put an id of one of the skus that I have in my storage model and when I GET the product I want it to show the info about that sku I have search for an answer for this for days and I can not find a solution

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    stores:[{
        name:String,
        package:[{
            name:String,
            sku: // i want here to pass one of the skus id and when i populate the product i want it to return that sku info
        }]
    }],

},{timestamps : true})
export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);


const storageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    region:[{
        name:String,
        skus:[{
            name:String,
            variant:[{
                name:String,
            }]
        }]
}]
},{timestamps: true})
export default mongoose.models.Storage || mongoose.model("Storage", storageSchema);

//example of the resposnse i want 
{
    "_id": "6402ec724db3304dfc134069",
    "name": "product Name",
    "stores": [
        {
            "name": "Store Name",
            "package": [
                {
                    "name": "package name",
                    "sku" : [{
                        "name":"sku name",
                        "variant":[{
                            "name":"variant name"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"variant name"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"variant name"
                        },
                        {
                            "name":"variant name"
                        },]
                    }]
                    "_id": "6402ee69c737a9d40948d522"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "6402ede4c737a9d40948d4f9"
        }
    ],
}

//example of the storage data 
{
    "_id": "63f43de1b8604ed5c5c99f02",
    "StorageName": "Storage Name",
    "region": [
        {
            "name": "region name",
            "_id": "63f43e9eb8604ed5c5c99f48",
            "skus": [
                {
                    "name": "first sku",
                    "variant":[{
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },],
                    "_id": "63f4c734b8604ed5c5c99f99"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sec sku",
                    "variant":[{
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"variant name"
                    },],
                    "_id": "63f4c73ab8604ed5c5c99fa7"
                },
                {
                    "name": "third sku",
                    "_id": "6402baac4db3304dfc133db7"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "region name",
            "_id": "63f43ea9b8604ed5c5c99f5b",
            "skus": [
                {
                    "name": "first sku",
                    "_id": "63f4db42cfb1ebe9fafc1ff0"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sec sku",
                    "_id": "63f4db4dcfb1ebe9fafc200a"
                },
                {
                    "name": "third sku",
                    "_id": "63f4db5ccfb1ebe9fafc2027"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the model `storegas`, you dont need to store `name` in fields `stores` and `package` of model `Product` because we can get them from `storage`

it would be like :

```
//product model
{
    name:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    stores:[
        {
            storeId:String,
            package:[{
                skuId: string
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

except you have another purpose, we can do it with `lookup` and `pipeline`

and i believe you also have collections for `region` and `skus`, you should post them as well because it would be easier to join with those collections rather than with only `product` and `storage`

Noted:

- do `filter` as much as you can in `$match` for better performance
- if your data have a large size of the documents, use `pagination` because we are doing `recurring` query

to approach your requirements to `search for sku of product`, it would be like below

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "6402ec724db3304dfc134069",

      // i suggest to filter with storege id
      //"stores._id": "63f43de1b8604ed5c5c99f02"
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$stores"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "storages",
      let: {
        storeID: {
          "$toString": "$stores._id"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$storeID"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$StorageName",
            "package": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$region",
                    "as": "region",
                    "in": {
                      "_id": "$$region._id",
                      "name": "$$region.name",
                      "sku": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$region.skus",
                          "as": "sku",
                          "cond": {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$sku._id",
                              "63f4c734b8604ed5c5c99f99", //filter the id of sku
                              
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "as": "region",
                "cond": {
                  "$ne": [
                    "$$region.sku",
                    []
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            
          },
          
        }
      ],
      as: "stores"
    }
  },
])
```

try it in [MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_kfHnW5TW0b)